# Fox-Toolkit Configure Colors

Tags: fox-toolkit

Is it possible to configure the background color of a fox-toolkit application? I want to add a dark-mode (i.e. set background color of all widgets to black) which can be turned on and off by the user.

Comment: By means of example, Xfe is a FOX application that allows different background colours to be used: http://roland65.free.fr/xfe/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use fox registry and set colour settings

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I was looking for. I am just going to add a link to the fox registry documentation here for future reference: http://www.fox-toolkit.org/registry.html